# batch file to activate env and run spyder. CMD remains open

Tags: python, batch-file, anaconda, spyder

I created a simple batch file to activate an Environment and then run spyder.

```
@echo off
call activate env
spyder.exe
exit
```

Now the problem is that the CMD remains open after the execution and it's attached to spyder meaning that if I close it Spyder exits as well with the following message.

```
forrtl: error (200): program aborting due to window-CLOSE event
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
libifcoremd.dll    00007FF8D20694C4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNELBASE.dll     00007FF917927EDD  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
KERNEL32.DLL       00007FF918D91FE4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
ntdll.dll          00007FF91ACECB31  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

I actually tried the following code as well, after suggestions from here and other similar posts. The only difference now is that cmd closes but another window stays open in its place. The [icon](http://prntscr.com/kg4va4) of the new window is not the cmd icon.

```
@echo off
call activate env
start spyder.exe
exit
```

Furthermore, I tried

```
cmd "/c activate env && start spyder"
```

which has the same result as the first batch

```
cmd "/c activate env && spyder && exit"
```

which exits before it does anything
and

```
cmd "/c activate env && start spyder && exit"
```

which has the same result as the second batch

Does anyone have a solution to that? Thanks

Comment: try `start spyder.exe`

Comment: I 've tried it before, but I tried it now as well, with the same results.

Comment: then [edit] your question to add the "start" part, explain that start doesn't work and what it does exactly. Because every time I have tried it it worked.

Comment: I edit it! thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: good edit, reopening.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you're trying to do by pasting the following into a batch file (.bat) or a shortcut path:

```
C:\Anaconda3\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\cwp.py C:\Anaconda3\envs\py38 C:\Anaconda3\envs\py38\pythonw.exe C:\Anaconda3\envs\py38\Scripts\spyder-script.py
```

This will activate the python environment called py38 and launch spyder without opening the cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the small extra program [RUNNHIDE](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/csharpexamples.php#RunNHide), as documented on [Rob van der Woude's](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_hideconsole.php) site.

```
RUNNHIDE.EXE spyder.exe
```